# Converting FPDF from MYSQL to SQL SERVER

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, fpdf, sqlsrv

I am working on to convert my FPDF generator from mysql to SQL server. And having some few issues. In the mysql_table.php file I am very unsure what to replace the mysql with to make it SQL SERVER compatible. I have marked with HERE where its mysql code.

This is my generatepdf.php file:

```
<?php

require('mysql_table.php');

 $timezone = "Europe/Oslo";
 date_default_timezone_set($timezone);
 $format="%H%M%S";
$strf=strftime($format);

 if(isset($_POST['submit']))

{



class PDF extends PDF_MySQL_Table
{


function Header()
{
    //Title
    $this->SetFont('Arial','',18);
    $this->Cell(0,6,'Measurement',0,1,'C');
    $this->Ln(10);
    //Ensure table header is output
    parent::Header();
}
}

//Connect to database
$conn_array = array (
"UID" => "sa",
"PWD" => "root",
"Database" => "chart",
) ;
$conn = sqlsrv_connect('BILAL' , $conn_array);


$pdf=new PDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
//First table: put all columns automatically
$pdf->Table($conn, "SELECT PH, Temperature FROM chartgoogle");
$prop=array('HeaderColor'=>array(255,150,100),
            'color1'=>array(210,245,255),
            'color2'=>array(255,255,210),
            'padding'=>2);
$pdf->Output($downloadfilename."$strf.pdf"); 
header('Location: '.$downloadfilename."$strf.pdf");
}
?>
```

mysql_table.php file (The HERE are where there is mysql code)

```
    <?php
    require('fpdf.php');

    class PDF_MySQL_Table extends FPDF
    {
    var $ProcessingTable=false;
    var $aCols=array();
    var $TableX;
    var $HeaderColor;
    var $RowColors;
    var $ColorIndex;



    function Footer()
    {
        //Position at 1.5 cm from bottom
        $this->SetY(-10);
        //Arial italic 12
        $this->SetFont('Arial','I',12);
        //Page number
        $this->Cell(0,10,'Page '.$this->PageNo().'',0,0,'C');
    }



    function Header()
    {
        //Print the table header if necessary
        if($this->ProcessingTable)
            $this->TableHeader();
    }

    function TableHeader()
    {
        $this->SetFont('Arial','B',12);
        $this->SetX($this->TableX);
        $fill=!empty($this->HeaderColor);
        if($fill)
            $this->SetFillColor($this->HeaderColor[0],$this->HeaderColor[1],$this->HeaderColor[2]);
        foreach($this->aCols as $col)
            $this->Cell($col['w'],6,$col['c'],1,0,'C',$fill);
        $this->Ln();
    }

    function Row($data)
    {
        $this->SetX($this->TableX);
        $ci=$this->ColorIndex;
        $fill=!empty($this->RowColors[$ci]);
        if($fill)
            $this->SetFillColor($this->RowColors[$ci][0],$this->RowColors[$ci][1],$this->RowColors[$ci][2]);
        foreach($this->aCols as $col)
            $this->Cell($col['w'],5,$data[$col['f']],1,0,$col['a'],$fill);
        $this->Ln();
        $this->ColorIndex=1-$ci;
    }

    function CalcWidths($width,$align)
    {
        //Compute the widths of the columns
        $TableWidth=0;
        foreach($this->aCols as $i=>$col)
        {
            $w=$col['w'];
            if($w==-1)
                $w=$width/count($this->aCols);
            elseif(substr($w,-1)=='%')
                $w=$w/100*$width;
            $this->aCols[$i]['w']=$w;
            $TableWidth+=$w;
        }
        //Compute the abscissa of the table
        if($align=='C')
            $this->TableX=max(($this->w-$TableWidth)/2,0);
        elseif($align=='R')
            $this->TableX=max($this->w-$this->rMargin-$TableWidth,0);
        else
            $this->TableX=$this->lMargin;
    }

    function AddCol($field=-1,$width=-1,$caption='',$align='L')
    {
        //Add a column to the table
        if($field==-1)
            $field=count($this->aCols);
        $this->aCols[]=array('f'=>$field,'c'=>$caption,'w'=>$width,'a'=>$align);
    }

    function Table($query,$prop=array())
    {
        //Issue query
 HERE   $res=mysql_query($query) or die('Error: '.mysql_error()."<BR>Query: $query");
        //Add all columns if none was specified
        if(count($this->aCols)==0)
        {
 HERE       $nb=mysql_num_fields($res);
            for($i=0;$i<$nb;$i++)
                $this->AddCol();
        }
        //Retrieve column names when not specified
        foreach($this->aCols as $i=>$col)
        {
            if($col['c']=='')
            {
                if(is_string($col['f']))
                    $this->aCols[$i]['c']=ucfirst($col['f']);
                else
  HERE      $this->aCols[$i] ['c']=ucfirst(mysql_field_name($res,$col['f']));
            }
        }
        //Handle properties
        if(!isset($prop['width']))
            $prop['width']=0;
        if($prop['width']==0)
            $prop['width']=$this->w-$this->lMargin-$this->rMargin;
        if(!isset($prop['align']))
            $prop['align']='C';
        if(!isset($prop['padding']))
            $prop['padding']=$this->cMargin;
        $cMargin=$this->cMargin;
        $this->cMargin=$prop['padding'];
        if(!isset($prop['HeaderColor']))
            $prop['HeaderColor']=array();
        $this->HeaderColor=$prop['HeaderColor'];
        if(!isset($prop['color1']))
            $prop['color1']=array();
        if(!isset($prop['color2']))
            $prop['color2']=array();
        $this->RowColors=array($prop['color1'],$prop['color2']);
        //Compute column widths
        $this->CalcWidths($prop['width'],$prop['align']);
        //Print header
        $this->TableHeader();
        //Print rows
        $this->SetFont('Arial','',8);
        $this->ColorIndex=0;
        $this->ProcessingTable=true;
     HERE   while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))
                $this->Row($row);
            $this->ProcessingTable=false;
            $this->cMargin=$cMargin;
            $this->aCols=array();
        }
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: Are you planning to use the `sqlsrv` driver ? If so, the PHP manual have some explanations. For simple query, the syntax for sql and mysql are almost the same, except for certain things like mysql `LIMIT` is `TOP` in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to use this opportunity to use PDO, The first time setting this up can be tricky, however. Its not hard, but you need to complete a few steps.

```
$dsn = 'mssql:host=localhost;dbname=yourdbname';
$user = 'dbuser';
$password = 'dbpass';

try {
     $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
     echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

$Query = $dsn->prepare("select * from YourTable where `ID` = :id");
$Query->bindParam(':id', 1, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$Query->execute();

$rs = $q->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

In most cases you will need to download the SQL server drivers
   you can find the drivers here ->  http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098

You will also need the Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client installed

You also need to make sure that the PDO and pdo_sqlsrv extensions are enabled.

Here is some documentation about PDO -> http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php

Here is an example application -> [http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff754357(v=sql.105).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff754357%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: They are different; each has its own benefits. I prefer PDO because I like OO with exceptions. Also PDO will be more DB neutral, which will make your life easier if you ever need to switch again. 
I believe the performance should be similar, but SQLSRV allows the data to be streamed to the DB.
I personally would go with the plain PDO, but you need to look at the requirements to see which will work best for your project. Check out some of the differences here -> http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brian_swan/archive/2010/04/20/comparing-the-sqlsrv-and-pdo-apis.aspx

Comment: By the way you would still need to install the drivers and native client.